# How can I use a Struts 1.x DispatchAction and have buttons with large text values on them?

Tags: struts, struts-1

All the DispatchAction examples have commands like "add", "show", and "delete".  What if I need to have text like "Submit this form for further processing!", but I don't want to name my DispatchActions's  method "submitThisFormForFurtherProcessing!" ? Is there a way I can have the text that shows on the submit button be different than the method name of the Struts Dispatch Action?

Answer (score 1):

got it - use "LookupDispatchAction" rather than "DispatchAction".  This has a method you need to override called Map getKeyMethodMap() that will map the button text to the name of the method that needs to get invoked for that button text.